# Cant pass all values of a form to a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have a form that need to pass its values to backend and receive the response.

I am using jquery but if you know any other way to do it please do let me know.

I am doing it using the following code but it does not receive the values, also I am not sure how to send them to backend once received the response.

```
$('#myform').on("submit",function(event){
    var mydata = $('myform').serialize();
    alert(mydata); 
});


<s:form id="myform">
    <s:textfield name="name" label="name"/>
    <s:textfield name="family" label="family"/>
    <s:submit validate="true"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML rather than the struts code, and please post the value of `mydata`.

Comment: can you define what you mean by not able to pass all values?? what all value are being passed to actions and what are not? also show your action code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
var mydata = $('myform').serialize();
```

to

```
var mydata = $('#myform').serialize();
```

You should use [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and not [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) in this case.